# Fullcalendar - Http Get request not returning the desired JSON data

Tags: php, json, laravel, fullcalendar

I am running a laravel 10 application with php version 8.1 , I followed a guide on how to implement fullcalendar with AJAX - The author used laravel 8 - although i followed a lot of other guides even ones using vue.js. I have not succeeded with those and this guide I came the furthest - I am able to post data into the database when creating an event and can view it in the database also able to delete the added event before refresh.

I know it is probably a php version issue but I am not getting to the root cause

Please see below a screenshot of data not returning to the calendar after refresh:

[image: Data not returning to calendar after refresh]

Successfully able to add to event to the database:

[image: Event Succesfully added]

Data added to database:

[image]

I have read through the laravel Documentation to see if I can implement the JSON request on the website but also no success.

In the `calendar.blade.php` file this is what i have for the GET request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var SITEURL = "{{ url('/') }}";
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            var calendar = $('#full_calendar_events').fullCalendar({
                editable: true,
                editable: true,
                events: SITEURL + "/calendar-event",
                displayEventTime: true,
                eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
                    if (event.allDay === 'true') {
                        event.allDay = true;
                    } else {
                        event.allDay = false;
                    }
                },
```

In the Model I have:

```
      class CrudEvents extends Model
      {
         use HasFactory;
         protected $fillable = [
          'event_name', 
          'event_start', 
          'event_end'
         ];    
       }
```

In the Controller I have

```
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
        if($request->ajax()) {  
             $data = CrudEvents::whereDate('event_start', '>=', $request->start)
                 ->whereDate('event_end',   '<=', $request->end)
                 ->get(['id', 'event_name', 'event_start', 'event_end']);
             return response()->json($data);
        }
        return view('calendar');
    }
```

These are my migrations

```
     public function up(): void
     {
         Schema::create('crud_events', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('event_name');
            $table->date('event_start');
            $table->date('event_end');            
            $table->timestamps();
         });
     }
```

Comment: `I followed a guide on how to implement fullcalendar with AJAX`...looks like you followed a really old guide, since it appears you implemented fullcalendar 3, which is obsolete and gets no updates. If you're starting a new project, use the latest version (6.x) for less dependencies, more features, better performance and fewer bugs. https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc

Comment: So...when you're loading your blade view, have your Developer Tools open in the browser. Go to the Network are. Look at the XHR request to `/calendar-event` which appears. Click to open it. Go to the Response tab. What do you see there? Is it valid JSON, with the property names that fullcalendar expects? [edit] your question with the data you find there (as text please, not a picture) if you're unsure. That's the starting poinf of debugging whether it's returning valid event data to the calendar or not.

Comment: P.S. It's unclear what your second screenshot (`Successfully able to add to event to the database`) is the result of? How did that event get into the calendar? Did you add data to the database manually? Or you used JS to add it to fullCalendar directly or something? Your description doesn't really explain clearly what is the difference between those two scenarios. I assume in that picture we are looking at event ID 5 from your data screenshot though? So it did load it from the database? If so then it's even more confusing as to what scenario the first screenshot is intended to represent...

Comment: ...you say it's after a "refresh". Refresh of what? You mean pressing F5 in the browser? That shouldn't make any difference - it would just re-load the events from the database (but you can follow the steps in my second comment to verify whether that's actually happening or not).